ckeditor is not good for django anymore
before ckeditor worked for django but now it is not working and expired.
django by itself suggest non-free ckeditor 4 LTS or ckeditor 5 but I don't know how to use it please if there is give me another editor for django or guide me for this ckeditor.
it is the warning message:
WARNINGS:
?: (ckeditor.W001) django-ckeditor bundles CKEditor 4.22.1 which isn't supported anmyore and which does have unfixed security issues, see for example https://ckeditor.com/cke4/release/CKEditor-4.24.0-LTS . You should consider strongly switching to a different editor (maybe CKEditor 5 respectively django-ckeditor-5 after checking whether the CKEditor 5 license terms work for you) or switch to the non-free CKEditor 4 LTS package. See https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4-support/ for more on this. (Note! This notice has been added by the django-ckeditor developers and we are not affiliated with CKSource and were not involved in the licensing change, so please refrain from complaining to us. Thanks.)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use github.com/hvlads/django-ckeditor
You can install it with
pip install django-ckeditor-5

further instructions can be found on the github page.
